# How to allow multiple select options based on input - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

Suppose, if the `people` input value is `1`, then the select option for value 1 and 2 will be selectable and if the `people` value is `>1`, the rest of them will be selectable.

Is it possible to allow multiple select options that can be selectable based on the input?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("input", "#people, #intRooms", function() {

        var people = $('#people').val();
        var intRooms = $('#intRooms').val();
        if (people == 1) {
            $('#intRooms').val('1').change();
        } else {
            $('#intRooms').val('3').change();
        }

        $('#cost').html('The cose is ' + (people * intRooms));

    });

    $("#people").trigger("input");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
People:<input name="people" id="people" type="number">
<div class="container">
   <div>
      <b>Intended Rooms:</b><br>
      <select id="intRooms">
         <option value="1">1 Room</option>
         <option value="2" >2 Rooms</option>
         <option value="3">3 Rooms</option>
         <option value="4">4 Rooms</option>
         <option value="5" >5 Rooms</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   Cost: <div id="cost">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't show other options if value is not greater than 1

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("input", "#people, #intRooms", function() {
        var people = $('#people').val();
        var intRooms = $('#intRooms').val();
        if (people > 1) {
            var html = '<option value="1">1 Room</option><option value="2" >2 Rooms</option><option value="3">3 Rooms</option><option value="4">4 Rooms</option><option value="5" >5 Rooms</option>'
            $('#intRooms').html(html);
        } else {
            var html = '<option value="1">1 Room</option><option value="2" >2 Rooms</option>'
            $('#intRooms').html(html);
        }

        $('#cost').html('The cose is ' + (people * intRooms));

    });

    $("#people").trigger("input");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
People:<input name="people" id="people" type="number">
<div class="container">
   <div>
      <b>Intended Rooms:</b><br>
      <select id="intRooms">
         <option value="1">1 Room</option>
         <option value="2" >2 Rooms</option>
         <option value="3">3 Rooms</option>
         <option value="4">4 Rooms</option>
         <option value="5" >5 Rooms</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   Cost:<br>
   <div id="cost">
   </div>
</div>
```